# Where are the files from an unlocked Package?

Tags: package, scratch-org

I am doing to refactor on my project, to take advantage of the unlocked package (without namespace) from Salesforce.

I was able to create a package, etc.

The only thing I have troubles understanding is...

**Where the packaged files are stored?**

I saw that all the package and stuff that we create are linked to the Devhub.

Using the CLI, I can see the packages, versions etc..

The only thing, I am curious to know where those files go.

So if my scratch org is expired, I create a new scratch org, I check out the code on my repo or I install the package, I update the project scratch org config. Than I can modify the packaged code, to create a new version.

**Is it the right method, when updating a package, after the scratch org is expired**?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package versions exist in your DevHub, any other changes to your files should be in your repo. The intent of DX is that your repo should be the "source of truth." This means that anything you care about should be in your repo. When creating a new scratch org, you should, in practice, be able to simply use force:source:push to deploy to a scratch org.